# Node.js Express Jade improve TTFB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to switch from PHP/Nginx to NodeJS Express Jade and i've created an app.js which contains all code needed to run NodeJS website, the problem is that TTFB takes ~ 1 second every time, i'm using GZIP and Caching. Below you can find my app.js code

```
var express          = require('express'); 
var subdomain        = require('express-subdomain');
var compression      = require('compression');
var fs               = require('fs');
var path             = require('path');
var mime             = require('mime-types');
var app              = express();
var router           = express.Router();
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
app.set('view engine','jade');

app.use(subdomain('cdn',router));
app.use(compression({level:9}));

router.get('*',function(req,resp,next){
    CDNDeliver(__dirname+'/cdn/'+req.url,function(data)
    {
       resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       resp.contentType(mime.contentType(path.extname(__dirname+'/cdn'+req.url)));
       resp.end(data);
    });
});

app.get('/',
        function(req,resp)
        {
            RenderView(resp,'index',
                        function(html)
                        {

                            resp.end(html);
                        }
                      );
        }
);

app.listen(80,function()
        {
            console.log('node.js started');
        }
);


var ViewCache = {}; 
function RenderView(resp,view,callback) {
   if(!ViewCache[view])
   {
      ViewCache[view] = resp.render(view);
      callback(ViewCache[view]);
   }
   else
      callback(ViewCache[view]);
}
var CDNCache = {};
function CDNDeliver(url,callback)
{
    if(!CDNCache[url])
    {
      fs.readFile(url,function(err,data)
        {
           if(!err)
              CDNCache[url]=data;
              callback(CDNCache[url]);
        })
    }
    else
    callback(CDNCache[url]);
}
```

[image: LoadTime]

Can anyone explain why the TTFB is so high, or how I can reduce it?

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce TTFB by switching from development to production. Set:

```
NODE_ENV=production
```